# DotNetNuke uninstalling modules and deleting files

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have recently completed Clinton Patterson's guide on DNN module development and was just playing around with the module that I have developed (reinstalling the module, uninstalling the module, etc).

However, some of my source files including `View.ascx, Settings.ascx, Edit.ascx, module.css, 00.00.01.SqlDataProvider, Uninstall.SqlProvider, ReleaseNotes.txt, License.txt` went missing all of a sudden and is nowhere to be found.

I am not too sure why this is happening but I am suspecting it's due to me uninstalling the module and selecting the "Delete Files?" option when uninstalling. Now I am unable to install the module anymore as all the files mentioned above can't be found in my project anymore.

So my question here is whether my assumption is correct in which I have 'accidentally' deleted my source file when uninstalling the module? And if so, is there any way that I can recover those files because I can't seem to find them anywhere (not even in the recycling bin).

Anyway, shouldn't uninstalling a module deletes those files that were installed and not touch the original source files? Sorry I am rather new to this and I can't really find any similiar questions about this online. Thank you very much!

P.S: I am using DotNetNuke Community Version **07.01.02** if that helps.

Uninstalling the module:
[image: Uninstalling the module]

Selecting the 'Delete Files?' option when uninstalling the module:
[image: The 'Delete Files?' option when uninstalling the module]

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that will remove the files if there's a PROJECT or SOLUTION file in the directory.

It's a safety catch for development environments. I would just manually delete them after you go though the uninstall process.

Comment: Oh hi! Hmm I have tried again just now by installing a new module and the source files mentioned are really deleted after I selected the "Delete Files?" option when uninstalling that module. Guess the only way is to redo the whole thing again. Oh well, need more practice anyways. Hahahahaaha. Thanks =D